# React: How to define the Homepage

Tags: reactjs

I got a problem in React that the root link (the homepage) has no content except the header and footer. I can easily switch between pages but in the "http://localhost:3000" there is no content except the header and footer.

The code is as follows this:

```
return (
  <>
    <Router>
      <Headernavbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/home/imagegallery' component={Homepage} />
        <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/abstract/imagegallery' component={Abstractcollection} />
        <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/documentary/imagegallery' component={Documentarycollection} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </>
);
```

I there any idea on how it should be done?

Comment: On your localhost you display only <Headernavbar /> component. You display homepage on different url:  localhost/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/home/imagegallery. Your homepage should be linked like this: <Route path='/' component={Homepage} />

Answer (score 0):

You can use * in the path like this:

```
return (
<>
  <Router>
    <Headernavbar />

    <Switch>

      <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/home/imagegallery' component={Homepage} />
      <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/abstract/imagegallery' component={Abstractcollection} />
      <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/documentary/imagegallery' component={Documentarycollection} />
      <Route path='*' component={Homepage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some content on

`http://localhost:3000`

You need to render a component at `path='/'`

eg. `<Route path="/" component={<App />}>`.
This means that whenever you hit `localhost:3000` it directs you to `/` by default.

Try to modify your code like so:

```js
<>
  <Router>
    <Headernavbar />

    <Switch>

      <Route path='/' component={Homepage} />
      <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/abstract/imagegallery' component={Abstractcollection} />
      <Route path='/sidenavigation/pages/galleries/documentary/imagegallery' component={Documentarycollection} />
      <Route path='*' component={Handle404Page} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</>
```